# Raspberry Pi 4 Wifi not connecting with USB 3 SSD

Tags: wifi, usb, ssd, raspberry-pi

I am currently running the early access OS 6 on a Raspberry Pi 4 with the Argon One M.2 case, and booting from the M.2 SSD.  When I have the SSD connected to either USB 3 port of the Pi, then I cannot connect to any wifi network, though it does still list the network. It simply times out and fails to connect.  However if I switch it over to either of the USB 2 ports then all works perfectly.

I also tried booting into Raspberry OS with the same setup (from the M.2 SSD).  That works fine.

I have seen discussions on other websites about known issues with the USB 3 standard and wifi, but I do not think this is the problem here, because Raspberry OS works.

Could this be that Elementary OS is drawing more power, so maybe I need a larger power adapter?  I have no other clues as to what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For clarification: if you boot from the USB2 using your SSD, do both of the other USB3 drives continue to work as expected for other purposes (e.g., will other flash drives or devices work at high speeds in the USB3 ports)?.  Will wifi work as expected when the USB3 ports are being used?

P.S. I have heard that wifi 2.4 won't work when anything is plugged into USB3, but wifi 5.0 still works.  According to the following link, this is a known issue: https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1430.